# Question about independence of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider an interval $[0,T]$ such that $\Delta t = \frac{T}{N}$ where $N$ is the number of sub-intervals. Therefore, we have uniform step-size $\Delta t.$ Also, $t_n = n \Delta t$ for $n = 0,1,2,\ldots,N.$

Let $[0,L]$ be another interval such that $\Delta x = \frac{L}{P}$ where $P$ is the number of sub-intervals. We have another uniform step-size $\Delta x.$ Also, $x_p = p \Delta x$ for $p = 0,1,2,\ldots,P.$

Suppose $\gamma_p = \frac{x_p \Delta t}{2 \Delta x}.$ My lecture slides say $\gamma_p$ is independent of $n.$ Why should that be ? If I replace $\Delta t$ by $\frac{t_n}{n},$ then $\gamma_p = \frac{x_p t_n}{2 n\Delta x }$ for $n = 1,2,\ldots,N.$ So there is $n$ appearing explicitly, and thus, my question.

Similarly, suppose $\beta_p = x_p t_n$ ? Is $\beta_p$ independent of $\Delta t?$

Comment: What is $S_p$? $\Delta S$?

Comment: @martini edited the question . It should be $x_p$ and $\Delta x.$

Comment: Capital $N$ (Number of sub-intervals) versus lower case $n$ (Index of sub-interval).

Comment: @Ned Didn't get you. could you elaborate ?

Comment: Replace (delta t) by $T/N$ not $T/n$

Comment: @Ned okay but why can't I replace $\Delta t$ by $\frac{t_n}{n}?$

Comment: you can but then it can be simplified to $T/N$, the same way that $(x - x +y)$ is independent of $x$ even though an $x$ is written there.